# Filter order collection using custom field: Magento

Tags: collections, filter, magento

I added a custom field(sales_code) in order table(sales_flat_order) manually.

Now I want to filter the order collection (in admin order gird page) using that custom field. But magento throws an error.

My Code:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('sales_code', '123456');
$collection->getSelect()->where('sales_code="123456"');
```

Error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sales_code' in 'where clause'
```

Is there any way to filter the collection using custom field in magento.

Comment: In this sort of situation I tend to `echo (string) $collection->getSelect()` and then paste the query into PhpMySQL, the error messages are sometimes clearer and having the table names is a help too.

Comment: (1) Which version of Magento? (2) Does "manually" mean you added a column to the table directly?

Comment: 1 - Magento ver-1.6.1.0
2 - Yes, I added directly.

Comment: clockworkgeek idea helps me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem I use the sales_flat_order_grid table instead of table sales_flat_order.